# Jquery .On is not working, where .live is working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

A grid header contains all the Columns Names with check boxes, the last column is Re-Assign column with Check box. All the cells in the last column contains checkboxes. So, once I check the checkbox in the header all the checkboxes in that perticular column get checks. For this I used jquery with .live, its working 100% perfect. But if I want to use .On instead of .live its not working. Here I am keeping the jquery code and its libraries. Please help me in this issue. Thanks in advance.

jquery for .live:
 $("#<%=rgCaseRM.ClientID%> input[id*='chkHeaderRM']:checkbox").live("click", function () {

```
        var chkHeader = $(this);
        $("#<%=rgCaseRM.ClientID%> input[id*='chkReAssign']").each(function (index) {
            if (chkHeader.is(":checked")) {
                $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
                $(this).attr('checked', true);
                $("#<%=divRM.ClientID%>").show();
            }
            else {
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
                $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
                $("#<%=divRM.ClientID%>").hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

$("#<%=rgCaseRM.ClientID%> input[id*='chkReAssign']:checkbox").live("click", function () {
            var grid = $(this).closest("table");
            var chkHeader = $("#<%=rgCaseRM.ClientID%> input[id*='chkHeaderRM']:checkbox");
            if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
                chkHeader.removeAttr("checked");
            } else {
                $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
                if ($("[id*=chkReAssign]", grid).length == $("[id*=chkReAssign]:checked", grid).length) {
                    chkHeader.attr("checked", "checked");
                }
            }
            var checkedCheckboxes = $("#<%=rgCaseRM.ClientID%> input[id*='chkReAssign']:checkbox:checked").size();

```
        if (checkedCheckboxes > 0) {
            $("#<%=divRM.ClientID%>").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#<%=divRM.ClientID%>").hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `.on()` isn't just a drop in replacement for `.live()`, you need to add a selector for a parent element to attach the delegate listener to, as @Aruna points out below

Answer (score 1):

To replace the below 'live' to 'on',

```
$('selector').live('event', func);
```

You have to change this as,

```
$(document).on('event', 'selector', func);
```